# UNIQUE KEYWORD in SQL with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT S.name, H.pop
FROM HOME H
INNER JOIN STATE S
ON S.name = H.pop
WHERE H.pop >= 10000 ;
```

I want the name to become unique, I have tried a few different things. But I am struggling to find a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can use `GROUP BY S.Name` but you need to aggregate column `H.pop`.

Comment: what if you have a result like this: `Name, Pop`, `A, 100`, `A, 200`, `A, 300`, `B, 200`. The result of B is `B, 200` and what will be for `A`?

Comment: Joining the states name to the home's pop(ulation?) doesn't look right. Can you provide a small sample of the data you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.name, S.name AS pop --SINCE BOTH ARE SAME
FROM HOME H
INNER JOIN STATE S
ON S.name = H.pop
WHERE H.pop >= 10000 ;
```

Comment: This is only right because the join most likely is wrong <g>. As OP hasn't provided an answer to my comment on that, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,  I think J W's comment is a good one.  You can try:

```
SELECT S.name, sum(H.pop)
FROM HOME H
INNER JOIN STATE S
  ON S.name = H.pop
WHERE H.pop >= 10000 
GROUP BY S.name;
```

or

```
SELECT distinct S.name, H.pop
FROM HOME H
INNER JOIN STATE S
  ON S.name = H.pop
WHERE H.pop >= 10000;
```

Comment: before you have edited your answer, it won't because you have `GROUP BY` clause. but now, your second query will do the same thing, imagine the result will look like this `Name, Pop`, `A, 100`, `A, 200`, `A, 300`, how will `A` be unique?

Comment: Need OP to answer that, and tell us what the granularity of the two tables are.

Comment: JW, has a good point indeed. And I can't tell you why the question I am trying to answer has been asked this way. And it's been troubling me for the past few hours.

Comment: There would be 8 total results for >= 10000. But there would be only 5 names. And no where in the question, does it ask for a sum, aggregate or anything similar.

Comment: Totally fair. So why don't you refine your question to JW's point.  Specify the granularity of the tables, and say precisely what you want to get as a result.

Comment: Lets say I have 
a, 100
b, 200
c, 50
c, 900
c, 800
d, 450
d, 500

a through d shall be home, and the the numbers are the pop(ulation)

From what I see, with my little knowledge the only way I could get this to work with UNIQUE would be either to SUM or average like JW mentioned. But in the question I received, it doesn't ask for this. Just says any name should only be listed once.

Comment: Is this homework?  And who asked that question? Send it back to them.  Santosh's answer is particularly good here...